# Problemas con codificacion en Base64 C#

Tags: c#, base64

Al tratar de realizar estas funciones (con salt siendo una cadena de 32 caracteres y pass una cadena de un numero variable de caracteres):

```
public static string encodePassword(string salt, string pass)
{
    pass = mod4(pass);  /// Necesitamos que la cadena sea multiplo de 4
    pass = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass));
    pass += salt;
    pass = mod4(pass);
    pass = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass));
    return pass;
}

private static string mod4(string a)
{
    int mod4 = a.Length % 4;
    if (mod4 > 0)
    {
        a += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Siempre da el error: `System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.`

Qué puede estar causando el problema?

La funcion mod4 se ha extraido de [esta pregunta.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925959/6944709)

Comment: Yo lo he probado y no me da error. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de valores de parámetros con los que te genera el error?

Comment: Usar hash en lugar de base64 para contraseñas, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Su código está funcionando pero no lo recomiendo para contraseñas, mira aquí:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/V3FecE

**Para codificar contraseñas usa Hash, es más seguro**

Ejemplo:

```
public static string GetSha256FromString(string strData)
{
    var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strData);
    var hashString = new SHA256Managed();

    var hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
    return hashValue.Aggregate("", (current, x) => current + $"{x:x2}");
}
```

Mi ejemplo en GitHub
https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/WebAPIBase.NetCore/blob/master/Utils/HashUtil.cs